# Subtracting cells only if they have a value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I want to subtract two cells in excel but only if both cells have a value.  More specifiaclly in my case the formula in cell E2 is currently =D2-C2 but I only want this to be calculated when D2 has a value.
(D2=winnings, C2=stake and E2 = profit/loss.  I don't want the profit loss calculated until the winnings cell is completed.)

Can anyone help please?

Steve

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Place the following formula in cell E2 to achieve what you want:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D2),"",D2-C2)
```

If you want both cells to have a value:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(D2),ISBLANK(C2)),"",D2-C2)
```

Comment: If both C2 and D2 are required to have a value, shouldn't you use `=IF(AND(ISBLANK(D2),ISBLANK(C2)),"",D2-C2)` instead?

Comment: @Gareth: No. If you use `AND` here, it means: If **both** D2 and C2 is blank, return an empty cell, otherwise (both OR one of them has a value) return D2-C2. We have to use `OR` so we mean: If any member of the set (D2 or C2) is blank, return an empty cell. Otherwise (both having a value), return D2-C2.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but these don't seem to work.  It comes back FALSE.  Can you provide a solution please?

Comment: Forgive me all terribly.  Mehper's solutions worked a treat.  I don't know what happened earlier.  I think I need to get to bed.  I'm ever so grateful you're a star!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in cell E2:

```
=IF(AND(D2<>"",C2<>""),D2-C2,"")
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't help either.. thanks for your help.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Gareth Can you help again too?

Comment: Ah actually this also worked.  Thanks for your time and effort.  i don't know why I didn't think it worked earlier.

Comment: @Rack, if it was the answer can you please mark it as answer. Regards

Comment: @Rack just to point out I only edited the answer, the answer actually came from @chris neilsen :)

Comment: @Gareth @chris neilsen I did realise that but I understood that if I replied Chris would automatically be notified as 'The post author will automatically be notified of your comment'. Is that correct or am I the post author in this case?

Comment: @Gareth @chris neilsen Thinking about it I guess I am.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible reasons why both solutions didn't work at first:
1) Calculation was set to Manual
2) A cell in question was not really blank (maybe had a space or tab leftover from import)

1 is not too likely. You can cover 2 by using ISNUMBER instead of ISBLANK, and AND instead of OR (say that ten times fast...), as follows:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(D2),ISNUMBER(C2)),D2-C2,"")
```

Comment: Thx for your help though